# Hmailserver and roundcube does not connect

Tags: configuration, roundcube, hmail-server

I've been running my own mail server on a windows vm and roundcube on in an unraid docker container for over 2 years now. Recently I changed ISP's and got their new 5G router(NR5103E). Ever since then Roundcube just gives me an IMAP error:

```
IMAP Error: Login failed for noreply@domain.com against mail.domain.com from 188.x.x.140. Could not connect to mail.domain.com:143: Connection timed out in /var/www/html/program/lib/Roundcube/rcube_imap.php on line 211 (POST /?_task=login&_action=login)
```

Other mail clients work fine. Windows built in one, iOS web client, edison mail, thunderbird, all those work fine.

Completely wiped and reinstalled mysql and roundcube instalations, with no change.
Played with DNS settings both in router and unraid.
Mail server does not use certificates, so nothing to change there.
Tried a new mail server with no change.
Swapped back to my old router which is still on the old ISP and roundcube connects

Answer (score 0):

After trying different things, with my router, docker setup, vm configuration I ended up installing apache, sql and roundcube on the Windows vm with hmailserver and now it is just working.
Makes 0 sense...